# How do i create tag cloud in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tags, drupal-modules, tag-cloud

I have found Drupal [Tagadelic](http://drupal.org/project/tagadelic) module. As of now, [its](http://drupal.org/node/1129342) not suitable for Drupal 7.

Could you please any one tell me How do i create tag cloud in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a static tag cloud with http://drupal.org/project/tagclouds. For a nice flash (dynamic) version, try the devel version of http://drupal.org/project/cumulus

EDIT

You can already use tagadelic for Drupal 7 for a **dynamic** tag cloud. It is available on github: https://github.com/berkes/tagadelic/tree/7.x-1.x

*The Drupal7 branch is found there as well. It is reported as stable and usable, but needs refactoring and better testing until being released on drupal.org.*

Since tagadelic doesn't make changes to the database, only displays taxonomy, worst thing that could happen is that the page which displays the tag cloud crashes...

Comment: Actually, these are dynamic tag clouds, they move over the screen and react to your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

And when you do as [dorien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496362/dorien) says, be sure that your cron jobs are setup properly. Tagclouds can get out of sync if you're cron jobs aren't firing often enough. This leads to emtpy tags showing in a tag cloud and the improper weighting (sizing) of the linked tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt Tagedelic 7.x-1.x-dev for your site: https://drupal.org/node/1160134
Personally I'm disliking the 2.x version.

It is unmaintained and not recommended by the author but it was working out of the box for us. Anyways, we forked this version and adapted it for our needs. Check out our blog tags: https://www.abgeordnetenwatch.de/tagadelic

Its a good start if you plan to develop with it anyways.